# iCarousel configuration task

Tags: ios, icarousel

I using iCarousel library, to scroll many UIViews on my screen. Each view fills the entire screen.

I need to configure iCarousel in a way, to scroll only one view with short touch.

Now, I have

```
carousel.scrollSpeed = 0.1;
```

But to scroll from one screen to another, I need to slide finger across the screen from one side to another.
If I set `scrollSpeed` parametr to higher value, many UIViews scrolled, but I need to configure to scroll only one UIView per one touch.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would be to disable scrolling on the carousel itself and attach a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to detect when the user swipes in either direction, then call [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:1 animated:YES] if they swipe forwards, and [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:-1 animated:YES] if they swipe backwards.

EDIT:

Actually if the views fill the screen, I think an even better bet would be for you to use my SwipeView library instead of iCarousel. SwipeView has the same interface as iCarousel, but is based on a UIScrollView, so you can enable paging, set the numberOfItemsPerPage to 1 and have it behave in exactly the way you describe.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView

UPDATE:

The above info is outdated. iCarousel now supports single-page swiping by setting `pagingEnabled=YES`. That said, SwipeView may still be more appropriate if this is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this code will do the trick.

```
carousel.decelerationRate = 0.3;
```

Answer (score 1):

> The rate at which the carousel decelerates when flicked. Higher values mean slower deceleration. The default value is 0.95. Values should be in the range 0.0 (carousel stops immediately when released) to 1.0 (carousel continues indefinitely without slowing down, unless it reaches the end).

You should try a value between 0 and 0.5. It won't behave exactly like a scrollview, but that's the closest you can get it. Refer(https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/issues/94)

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this---

```
self.iCarosoul.decelerationRate=0.65;
self.iCarosoul.scrollSpeed=3;
self.iCarosoul.stopAtItemBoundary=YES
self.iCarosoul.scrollToItemBoundary=YES;
```